# Integrity constraints violation?

Tags: yii2

```
 $data = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('categoryMaster_id , categoryMaster_name,categoryMaster_image')
    ->from('categoryMaster')
    ->join('LEFT JOIN','productType', 'productType.categoryMaster_id = categoryMaster.categoryMaster_id')
    ->where('categoryMaster_id=:categoryMaster_id', ['categoryMaster_id' => $_GET['categoryMaster_id']])
    ->all();    
    return $data;
```

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'categoryMaster_id' in where clause is ambiguous\nThe SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `categoryMaster` LEFT JOIN `productType` ON productType.categoryMaster_id = categoryMaster.categoryMaster_id WHERE categoryMaster_id='1'","code":23000,"type":"yii\db\IntegrityException"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambiguous in `select`. add `categoryMaster.categoryMaster_id`

```
$data = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select('categoryMaster.categoryMaster_id, categoryMaster_name, categoryMaster_image')
->from('categoryMaster')
->join('LEFT JOIN','productType', 'productType.categoryMaster_id = categoryMaster.categoryMaster_id')
->where('categoryMaster.categoryMaster_id=:categoryMaster_id', ['categoryMaster_id' => $_GET['categoryMaster_id']])
->all();    
return $data;
```

Comment: same in where clause also. Thank you !